# I ask for clarification about ''not pass by reference'' in C

Tags: c, pointers, reference

After tried to compile `void some_function(int * & some_pointer);`and received the compiler error: `expected ';', ',' or ')' before '&' token.` I realized that I could only compile if the function had its reference removed to
 `void some_function(int * some_pointer);`

Researching I found the solution: "One cannot pass by reference in C". It will not compile that function.

However, it raised an eyebrow: `scanf("%d", &my_var);` We pass by reference all the time...
How is it working?
I assume we cannot create functions that ask for reference, by we can use reference as arguments. The program will pass it by value, and will change the original variable afterwards. Is it correct?

Or is the function asking for a pointer and when we use `&` it creates a pointer to that variable? I am very confused.

Comment: Passing the address of a variable (by value) is not pass by reference.

Comment: @Shawn: Passing the address of an object is passing by reference. “Passing by reference” means just that, passing some way of referring to an object, rather than passing the object’s value directly. C++ and other languages made this a feature directly provided by the language, so you could put an lvalue in an argument position, and the compiler would automatically pass it by a reference (which compilers largely implement by passing the address). But the do-it-yourself kind of passing an address is still passing by reference.

Comment: @Eric That _entirely_ depends on the level of abstraction with which you are communicating. C++ "references" are a _subset_ of ways to implement the broader computing concept of "pass by reference", and if you're talking in that sphere then "pass by reference" when you're passing a pointer is completely wrong. But then at other times it's completely right. It would be best to avoid making blanket statements on this topic because you will always be wrong, and you will simultaneously always be right, and you will simultaneously always confuse someone ;)

Comment: @Eric No. If it was pass by reference you could assign a new address to the passed pointer and have that change reflected in the caller, like when you assign a new value to a reference in C++. C only has pass by value; all function arguments are copied and changes to them are not visible to the caller. Modifying the value being pointed to shouldn't be confused with pass by reference, though it can kind of emulate the concept with an extra layer of indirection.

Comment: @Shawn: The pointed-to object is passed by reference. It can be changed by assigning a new value to it (via the lvalue formed by applying `*` to the pointer). The pointer is passed by value. I can tell you that, before C++ existed, we referred to passing things by reference when they were passed by address. C++ just provided a shorthand built-in way of doing this; it did not change the fact that it can be done the manual way as well, and that passing a reference (in the common English meaning) to something is passing by reference.

Comment: Fun fact: Certain other things existed before they were provided as built-in C++ features: sets, queues, algorithms, strings, and more. We even had ways of putting items into a chosen order without using `std::sort`. The fact that a string is implemented in C without using `std::string` or a set is implemented with a bitmap is implemented and without `std::set` does not mean they are not strings or sets. Some computers even provide built-in hardware stacks without using `std::stack`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Or is the function asking for a pointer and when we use & it creates a pointer to that variable?

That's exactly right.

In C++, the symbol `&` has multiple meanings:

- When applied as a unary operator in an expression, it means "take the address of", and produces a pointer;
- When part of a type like `int&` (or, indeed, `int*&`), it means "reference to";
- (And, when applied as a binary operator between two arithmetic expressions, it means "bitwise *AND*".)

With the choice of using `&` for reference types, the idea was, I think, to save creating new symbols and to try to create some symmetry between pointers and references. I don't think it worked; I think it's really confusing.

But for you, in C, it's moot, because (as you've discovered!) C does not have references. Instead your function could be written to take a pointer-to-pointer (`int**`). Ironically, you will probably need to use `&` at the call-site to present your argument to such a function!

As a further complication, you will sometimes hear the phrase "pass by reference" used in a broad sense. This is confusing in the realm of C++ because "reference" has this more specific meaning there. In fact, references were introduced in the C++ language specifically to make "pass by reference" more elegant and intuitive. But back in C, and more generally, it's just a way of saying "we're referring to a thing rather than copying it"; technically in C the way we do that is, indeed, to pass a *pointer*.

Answer (score 2):

While functions in C do not support pass by reference as you discovered, they can emulate pass by reference by accepting a pointer value, then when the function is called the address of a variable can be passed to it.  By doing that, the calling function can dereference the pointer and change the variable in the calling function.

For example:

```
void f(int *x)
{
    *x = 4;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    printf("x=%d\n", x);    // prints 0
    f(&x);
    printf("x=%d\n", x);    // prints 4
}
```

When we call the function like `f(&x)`, the `&` operator takes the address of its operand and passes that address to `f`.  It is *not* a reference.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, you cannot pass by reference in C. Instead, like in your `scanf()` example, you can pass the address of a variable (a.k.a, a pointer) by value to a function, and you can *pretend* that you have passed the variable by reference, but a literalist interpretation of your C code would not agree with that.

On the other hand you can use C++ references to truly pass a variable by reference. This mechanism, unlike the aforementioned one does not resort to [reification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reification_(computer_science)) of memory locations, i.e, in this instance, C++ (the language) doesn't know anything about the address of the variable (the C++ compiler does though).

So, in C,

- *you* can pass by reference (in an 'interpretive' sense).
- *your C code* itself can't pass anything by reference.

On the other hand, when using references in C++,

- *you* can pass by reference.
- *your C++ code* can also pass by reference.